# Выбор движка для блога

Tags: cms

Нужен, по сути, wordpress - его поюзал, но он не устроил (регистрация корявая, написание постов юзером - вообще через админку идёт).

Нужен движок с такими функциями:
возможность регистрации и написания своего поста (текста, блога);
возможность оценки этих постов другими пользователями;
вот в общем и всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какие вообще требования к движку? Язык, статика?

Есть, в общем, вот такая штука от выходца из Wordpress, как его легковесная замена: https://ghost.org/

Я лично предпочел бы свой блог написать сам на чем-нибудь типа [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (Python) или [revel](https://revel.github.io/) (golang). Но это если вам интересно вообще подобным заниматься и есть время.

Comment: @deterok да требований особых нет - язык - переведу,статику - не хочу, лучше cms с регистрацией. Хотелось бы бесплатный. (вся суть сайта - пользователи регистрируются и сами пишут статьи )
я так понял в друпале всё это есть из коробки?

Comment: Да, в Drupal'е много чего есть, но опять же на вкус и цет товарища нет. А ghost бесплатен, качаешь, разворачиваешь на серваке и поехал, что не так?

А про языки я имел в виду то, на каком написан движок.

В общем-то я бы не стал искать что-то готовое, хотя оно есть, а накидал бы себе сам тот функционал, который нужен, ведь на вкус и цвет товарища нет...

Answer (score 1):

Если нет задачи создания большого контентного сайта, то рекомендую воспользоваться сетевым сервисом для блогов (типа livejournal.com или blogger.com или любые другие). Вы избавитесь от головной боли от содержания сайта, да и дешевле будет. Также не маловажно где будут находится ваши друзья и подписчики. Раскрутится в сетевом сервисе легче.

Ну а если выделенный сайт, то Wordpress съедобный. Просто не умеете готовить.
Популярный, обновляемый, расширяемый.